# Show nothing if the field is null, but show the value if it's populated

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, confirmation

I want to hide the tr that holds the values %%CouponCode%%, %%CouponDiscount%% if the field is null/empty. Show the value if the fields are not null/empty. Here is my code below

```
%%[ 
var @hide
]%%

%%[If Not Empty(@hide) Then]%%

%%[ Set @hide = 'none' ]%%

%%[Else]%%

%%[ Set @hide = 'block' ]%%

%%[EndIf]%%

<tr style="display:%%= v(@hide) =%%;">
<td>
  <span class="span" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">Discount</span>
  <span class="span text-gray" style="color: #9a9a9a !important; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;(%%CouponCode%%)</span>
  <span class="span" style=" font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">:</span>
</td>
<td class="orders-summary__price align-right" style="border-collapse: collapse;font-weight: bold;color: #BC262D;" align="right">
  <span class="span" style="font-size: 16px;line-height: 20px;color: #BC262D;">%%CouponDiscount%%</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would show/hide on the server level to help reduce the total size of your email and the related processing.

Something like:

```html
%%[ 
Set @CouponCode = AttributeValue('CouponCode')
Set @CouponDiscount = AttributeValue('CouponDiscount')
]%%

<tr>
%%[if NOT EMPTY(@CouponCode) THEN]%%
<td>
  <span class="span" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">Discount</span>
  <span class="span text-gray" style="color: #9a9a9a !important; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;(%%CouponCode%%)</span>
  <span class="span" style=" font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">:</span>
</td>
%%[ENDIF]%%
%%[if NOT EMPTY(@CouponDiscount) THEN]%%
<td class="orders-summary__price align-right" style="border-collapse: collapse;font-weight: bold;color: #BC262D;" align="right">
  <span class="span" style="font-size: 16px;line-height: 20px;color: #BC262D;">%%CouponDiscount%%</span>
</td>
%%[ENDIF]%%
</tr>
```

Will allow you the flexibility to show one but not the other depending on values. Utilizing AttributeValue also allows you to handle if that field does not exist in the sendable data - returning null.

If you want to hide if either is empty, then you could do:

```html
%%[ 
Set @CouponCode = AttributeValue('CouponCode')
Set @CouponDiscount = AttributeValue('CouponDiscount')
]%%

%%[if NOT EMPTY(@CouponCode) AND NOT EMPTY(@CouponDiscount) THEN]%%
<tr>
<td>
  <span class="span" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">Discount</span>
  <span class="span text-gray" style="color: #9a9a9a !important; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;(%%CouponCode%%)</span>
  <span class="span" style=" font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;">:</span>
</td>
<td class="orders-summary__price align-right" style="border-collapse: collapse;font-weight: bold;color: #BC262D;" align="right">
  <span class="span" style="font-size: 16px;line-height: 20px;color: #BC262D;">%%CouponDiscount%%</span>
</td>
</tr>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message Invalid Script VAR Statement<br>An expected comma is not found in the variable declaration.

Comment: Crap sorry writing too much ssjs. Change the var to set

Comment: @DavisRousseau Edited my answer with the change

Comment: even with the values, being presented everything is showing as empty/null.

Comment: This will only display if both have a value. If either one is empty, it will be null. You can adjust the logic in the IF statement if you want it to be one or the other or similar.

Comment: sorry, again SSJS coding - need to add not empty() to it, cannot just have the var be true/false return like you can in JS.  Adjusted script and verified for sure it works now.

Comment: This is working perfectly